# Can a session cookie be set in Javascript so only that browser instance sees it?

Tags: javascript, session, browser, cookies

Is there a way to set a browser session cookie in Javascript, so that only that browser instance can see that cookie.  For example, if I set a cookie via Javascript in one instance of Firefox, and then invoke a second instance of Firefox (Ctrl-N or launching firefox.exe again), I do not want that second instance to be able see this cookie.

How would I go about this?  Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I thought that this might not be possible, but I needed some validation from other developers to confirm my suspicions.  I had searched on google as well, and I get the impression that this can only be accomplished on the server-side by maintaining cookies on the server, rather than the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Different browser windows are just different windows to the same instance. Launching Firefox again just spots the running instance and opens a new window in it.

(There are some command line options which might open a new instance (in particular the one to load a different user profile), but that is entirely a client issue and any JS is by the by).

Comment: David, thank you for the information. I had a feeling that would be the answer, but I needed validation.